# Saber si un usuario está registrado antes de autenticar con Google en Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Quiero autenticar a usuarios en mi aplicación web mediante Google y Facebook.
El caso es que solo quiero que puedan utilizar esta opción si el usuario previamente ya se ha registrado con su correo electrónico y contraseña.
Soy nuevo en este tema y la verdad es que no se me ocurre como podría hacer.
Estoy utilizando ReactJS

```
const GoogleLogin = () =>{
    return () =>{
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
            .then((data) =>{
                const statusUser = data.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
                    console.log(statusUser)
            }).catch((error) => {
                let errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorMessage)
            });
    }
}
```

La función retorna una promesa y muestro en consola el valor boleano que nos dice si el usuario es nuevo no. Me gustaría tener este dato antes de que el usuario haya sido logueado para saber si se registró anteriormente o se trata de un usuario nuevo, en este caso, no podría autenticarse.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar fetchSignInMethodsForEmail. Toma un correo electrónico y devuelve una promesa que se resuelve con la lista de proveedores vinculados a ese correo electrónico si ya está registrado, más información en la [documentación del método](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). Saludos!